# ListView items with two rows

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, onclick

This is my ListView structure and element :

```
     // Get a cursor with all phones
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Phones.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    /** ----Display the Contacts on the device----- */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, 
                    new String[] { Phones.NAME, Phones.NUMBER }, 
                    new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and my implementation of the setOnItemClickListener is as follows:

```
/** ----Defining the ItemOnClickListener for the displayed List---- */

    final ListView contactlistview = getListView();
    contactlistview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    contactlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(position));

            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    contactlistview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, contactlistview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

        }
    });
```

and finally got the ListView as :

[image: ListView Output]

and when i clicked on any of the item i get the Toast Displaying the Following:
[image: Toast Displays]

but i want my toast to display the contact name of the selected item

can u pls help me with the code :)

sorry for the inconvenience :)

THANKS :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the value of the object here.

Now try like this:

```
Cursor c = ((Cursor) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position));

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                   c.getString(Phone.NAME),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```